# What is the meaning of the notation $A^{\dagger}A\le I$, where $A$ is an operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, notation

I see this notation a lot (for example in [0] after eq. 1), but I cannot find a reference which explains what it means.  I suspect it means the eigenvalues are less than or equal to 1, but how would I know this?  Can you give a reference?

[0] Phys. Rev. A 64, 010101 (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0011111)

Comment: Eigen values depend on the boundary conditions and the units, so cannot be limited to 1. (energy levels for example, in units of electron volts , for the hydrogen atom for example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html

Comment: Indeed in every concrete physical case that $I$ includes a unit...

Comment: just looked at the link you give and realized it is quantum computing related, which has developed its own language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B \leq C$ means $\langle \psi| B\psi\rangle \leq \langle \psi |C \psi\rangle$ for every $\psi$ in the intersection of the domains of $B$ and $C$. In the case you consider, since $C=I$ and, assuming $A$ is defined on the whole Hilbert space because the space is finite dimensional $$\langle \psi| A^\dagger A\psi\rangle=\langle A\psi| A\psi\rangle = ||A\psi||^2$$
the requirement is equivalent to $||A|| \leq 1$.

As a consequence, since $\sup\{|\lambda| \:|\: \lambda \in spect(A)\} = ||A||$ you also have that every eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies $|\lambda| \leq 1$ as you suspect.

Comment: Please note that the OP is talking of *eigenvalues*  not eigenvectors, so the "suspicion" of the OP is wrong.